# Not able to push desired number of elements to the vector

Tags: c++, for-loop, stdvector

I am new to the `std::vector` class and was exploring ways of inserting elements into a vector as per the user request.
I've tried a loop to insert ten elements in a vector using the `push_back()` member function, but my vector is only storing nine elements, if I start the indexing from zero.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<vector>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
   vector<int> v1;
   for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
   {
       cin >> i;
       v1.push_back(i);
   }
}
```

I am using Visual Studio, and I am only able to insert nine elements into my vector. What can be the issue?

Comment: Are you aware that `cin>>i;` overwrites your loop variable?

Comment: yeah actually I wrote cin>>i by mistake of course it doesn't make sense. Thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 4):

You are replacing your loop variable `i` inside of the loop, meaning that you might not get ten iterations. If the user enters `10`, you would only get one iteration.

To solve this, you must use a separate variable for reading user input:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> v1;
    for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        int input;
        std::cin >> input;
        v1.push_back(input);
    }
}
```

---

I also recommend reading [Why is "using namespace std;" considered bad practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1452721)

Comment: Firstly ,Thanks for your response. I am totally aware of the fact the "using namespace std;" is considered a bad practise as it also includes the elements that we may not use at all which will result into wastage of memory. I only use it when I am coding short programs, to skip out writing "std::" again and again.

Comment: @ALOKKUMAR - do 'using std::vector;'